# Doubt in method of Undetermined Coefficients $(D^3+3D^2+2D)y=x^2$.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Solve $(D^3+3D^2+2D)y=x^2, D \equiv  \dfrac{d}{dx}$

Choosing, trial solution as $y=a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2$

If i substitute this in given differential equation,

$0+3(2a_2)+2(a_1+2a_2x)=x^2 $

Comparing corresponding coefficients, i get,

$a_0=0=a_1 = a_2$ --> it seems i made wrong some where, Pls correct me.

Comment: 0, -1, -2 are roots.... From this what can i infer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Try with $y_p=A+B x+C x^2+D x^3$ then
$$(D^3+3D^2+2D)y=(2 B + 6 C + 6 D)+ (4 C + 18 D)x+ 6 Dx^2\equiv x^2$$

Comment: Sir why do we need to take all derivatives from $x^3$?

Comment: $m=0$ is one of the roots of characteristic equation, so you should consider a polynomial with degree $deg(x^2)+1$.

Comment: But that case will be for $e^{ax}, a $ some constant....So here do we need to take a=0? Actually i am new. So asking u in detail.

Comment: No problem. this rule is when the right hand side is a polynomial. if $m=0$ wasn't one of characteristic equation roots, then you should consider a polynomial with degree $deg(x^2)$.

Comment: Thank you Sir. Actually that is not mentioned in my textbook. We can divide by D. So in Right hand side term becomes $x^3/3$. Now we can take derivatives of $x^3$ right?

Comment: You mean $(D^2+3D+2)y=\frac13x^3$ right?

Comment: Yes sir ........

Comment: In this case let $A + B x + C x^2 + D x^3$

Comment: got it sir, Tq...........

Answer (score 1):

$$(D^3+3D^2+2D)y=x^2,$$
If you integrate then you will see that you need a polynomial of at least degree 3
$$(D^2+3D+2)y=\frac {x^3}3+K_3$$
$$(D+1)(D+2)y=\frac {x^3}3+K_3$$
$$\implies y_h=K_1e^{-x}+K_2e^{-2x}$$
$$\implies y_p=ax^3+bx^2+cx$$